# Blockchain commercial paper demo

Tags: blockchain

Working on the commercial paper example as outlined here:

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/cp-web

Works fine until I try to log into my project here:

http://cp-web-jklondon-1411.mybluemix.net/login

Get error saying:

Waiting on the node server to open up so we can talk to the blockchain. This app is likely still starting up. Check the server logs if this message does not go away in 1 minute.
This application cannot run without the blockchain network :(

Whats going on?

Thanks
Rav

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix might have been unstable / the app is still staging. This actually happened quite frequently.